# Can not upload video to instagram with portrait mode

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I've faced such a strange experience. I'm trying to upload a video to my IG account using `instagram graph api` but it enables only `landscape mode`.

For example:

```
POST - https://graph.facebook.com/<account-id>/media?media_type=VIDEO&video_url=<1920x1080>.mp4
```

then it's ok, but if I try to upload

```
POST - https://graph.facebook.com/<account-id>/media?media_type=VIDEO&video_url=<1080x1920>.mp4
```

then the status code is "Error".

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Nowis Yes, I used a **video processing** package to reduce a bitrate and change the dimensions

Comment: I can't give you the exact code since as you can see I asked 10 months ago, but this [lib](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing) helped me